# Json object to Apostrophe array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I have json object like this

[
{
"tag": "search"
},
{
"tag": "test"
},
{
"tag": "css"
},
]

But i want to get this object like this

```
'search',
'test',
'css',
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Where does "apple" come from?!

Comment: $terms = [
                'search',
                'test',
                'css',
                'apple',
                'bear',
                'cat',
                'crabapple',
                'creep',
                'czar',
                'danger',
                'dominant',
                'doppler',
                'everclear',
                'evangelism',
                'frodo'
            ].sort(),

Comment: return $tags = Tag::select('tag')->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and extract the `tag` property value:

```js
const obj = [ { "tag": "search" }, { "tag": "test" }, { "tag": "css" }, ]

const res = obj.map(e=>e.tag)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Nothing showing when put res in [res]

Comment: @MDMasum What do you mean?

Comment: const obj = {!!$tags!!};
            const res = obj.map(e=>e.tag)


            var $terms = [res].sort(),
                $return = [];
                $return = [];

Comment: understand let me try

Comment: worked , thank's sir